# Import csv into mysql and then create multiple tables

Tags: mysql, csv

I have a csv file which I need to import into a MySQL database.

I need to split the data into multiple tables. An example is that it will contain booking and contact table. Basically the csv has currently got the data in one row.

So I was thinking of first importing into one table and then recursively going through each table and creating the relevant tables.

Just wondering if people have any other thoughts on this process?

Any tips would be great.

Cheers

Comment: Sounds good. I guess you could go ahead as follows: (A) import from csv into a temporary table as you described, (B) create derived tables from the initial table using "create table <tablename> as select ... from <initial_table> ... where ...". Yet I don't see any need for recursion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on how many tables you are talking about, I would say you are on the right track.

You could import the data into one table, RawData.

Then just run a few make table sql statements off of the data.

INSERT INTO new_contact_table (id, firstname, lastname) SELECT DISTINCT contact_id, contact_firstname, contact_lastname FROM RawData;

Then do the same thing with the bookings data.

Then create a third table linking the first two tables in a one to many or many to many fashion.

Comment: For a one to many relationship there is no need for a third table. A foreign key is sufficient.

Comment: @user152468 is correct.  If each booking has only one contact, the booking table can simply have a foreign key for the contact.  If you create the contact table first, then as you are inserting into the booking table you can select the identifying contact info against your already created contact table to put the contact id into the booking table.